# Change "Ctrl + Shift + U + unicode + enter" to "Alt + unicode". Is that possible? Where (which config) can I change it?

Tags: shortcut-keys, unicode, unicode-entry

I have found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>unicode</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> quite too long for «quoting the things», or 
 
• bulleting 
• it 
• up. 
However, on <strike>Windows</strike> another OS, it is quite cool: just hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, type your <kbd>code</kbd> on a numpad, and it appears.

The question is if it is possible to:

1. Change the shortcuts to just <kbd>Alt</kbd>? If yes, where it can be changed?
2. Automatically <kbd>Enter</kbd> unicode after stop holding the main shortcut?

Comment: Instead of ENTER you can hit any key (e.g. SPACE). And no need to keep CTRL+SHIFT pressed. I do CTRL-SHIFT-u (release), type unicode, press SPACE. But yes, something simpler would be nice.

Comment: Yeah, @PerlDuck, I don't hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shifut</kbd> either, but not doing this transforming to a more bulky sequence. When on <strike>Windows</strike> another OS you just release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with MATE DE `Ctrl+Shift+2603+Enter` works out the box (U2603 = ☃). On GNOME it may be customized in gnome-tweak I hope.

Comment: @N0rbert: That doesn't address OP's question. They obviously already know *how* to do it and want to *change* how it can be done.

Comment: If you don't find an answer I recommend using the Compose key. It's generally much more intuitive and you don't have to memorize as much. (For example, >> → », .- → ·, uu → ŭ, .. → …, etc.)

Comment: Since [ibus 1.5.15](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1885#issuecomment-284640278) ([this commit](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/commit/5ee3f48049ecf128391da6448ae7e74786bd171b)) shortcut setting is in ibus-setup, on ibus-panel-extension. Also, [as of 1.5.11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236817/209677), IBus uses dconf, its configuration obtained by: `dconf dump /desktop/ibus/`. Tell me if this works and turn to an answer. BTW, what keyboard/input source you have? Take a look to the keyboard layout, maybe is just there with AltGr+... .

Comment: @PabloBianchi, I use MS's Ergo Sculpt with mostly English, Russian, or Chinese inputs.
I will check your method, thanks in advance!